# grep to delete WordPress 'crunched' files

Tags: image, wordpress, grep

I'm trying to figure out how to grep a folder full of files that contain 3 versions of each file. The original and several resized versions of it. I would like to delete all files with a number 0-9 or dashes in their name with grep.

Can I simply add the characters to look for instead of (filename)?

```
./delete -r (filename)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're on Linux, you can use shell globbing to achieve this.

```
ls *[0-9-]*
```

If this gives you the files you want, you can delete them:

```
rm -i *[0-9-]*
```

Remove the `-i` if there are a lot of files.

Comment: This was a solid answer. I used cygwin for my Linux env.